# Change menu's height on scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I want for my website, when I scroll down to minimize the menu's height. For example, my header is fixed top with height:150px . And when I scroll down, I want to resize with a height: 50px.

I'm using **bootstrap 3.** So the class of my header is `.navbar .navbar-fixed-top .`

Can you tell how can I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the simple jquery solution.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop(); //set position from top when to change style in pixels
        if (y >= 300) {
            $('#header').addClass('resized');
        } else {
            $('#header').removeClass('resized');
        }
    });
```

CSS:

```
.resized {
    height:50px !important;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLkj7pcv/1/)**

Comment: For me it works with the HTML file on my computer but not online, an idea?